# display value of input field to another input field after submitting form in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've created a form in which I put values in input field and submit the form. But now I have to display those values into another input field after submitting the form. The other input field id is min2 which is outside the form.

```
/* begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false 

 language: lang-js */

    <script>
       const num3rs = val => val.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
        maximumFractionDigits: 0
    });
       document.getElementById("userInput3").addEventListener("input", function () {
                this.value = num3rs(+this.value.replace(/\D/g, ""))
                document.getElementById("min1").value = this.value
                
            })
       $("searchform").submit(function(){
      document.getElementById('userInput3').value = this.value;
      document.getElementById('min2').value = this.value;
    });
    </script>

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <form class="searchform">

       <input  name="Input.minp" id="Input.price.min" asp-for="Input.minp" />
       <input  id="userInput3" placeholder="min" style="height :30px;width:90px; border-style:solid ;border-color: black;border-radius:5px; margin-left:20px;margin-top:5px;">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton" id="searchButton" >
        submit
       </button>
    </form>
    <input id="min2" style="height :30px;width:70px; border:none;outline:none; margin-left:30px;" readonly>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: since those are supposed to be GET parameters sent to self, because the form has no action and method set, you should retrieve them in js this way https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: this form is just getting value from the  action. I want that the values which put in the form input field after click on submit button the values display on the other input field which is outside the form. kindly tell me what jquery i write

Comment: So you do not need page refresh on form submit? Then use `preventDefault()` first and then manipulate your input values.

Comment: no i have to  refresh but not that specific input field

Comment: What happens on this page refresh? Is your data sent to the back-end? You can retrieve the input value using your back-end language. Or take a look at the link Diego D provided.

Comment: it is my searching form i retrieve the data using filters .is that possible that after reloading the page a specific div not change.

Comment: One of the ways is to store the input value in local storage

Comment: @IvanBeliakov how to do this

Comment: Actually you don't even need local storage, session storage will be enough. Please read the information about `sessionStorage` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage